# Error while fetching nested loop output

Tags: sql

I want to generate a number triangle in PL/SQL like this,

If you pass 9 then it has to generate the given output.

```
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

If you pass 10 then it has to generate the given output.

```
12345678910
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Comment: I see no question and no source code.

Comment: Add your code, and error that you are getting

Comment: Here is the code that I am using                              DECLARE
   V   VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   FOR I IN REVERSE 1 .. 10
   LOOP
      FOR J IN 1 .. I
      LOOP
         V := V || ' ' || J;
      END LOOP;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V);
      V := NULL;
   END LOOP;
END;
/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1

```
DECLARE

V VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

FOR I IN REVERSE 1..5

LOOP

FOR J IN 1..I

LOOP

V:=V||' '||J;

END LOOP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V);

V:=NULL;

END LOOP;

END;

/
```

Comment: I like vote up if, my answer is usefull.